# What can I further assume about the speeds of runners of Lonely Runner Conjecture WLOG?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Lonely Runner Conjecture is the following problem, and the conjecture was proven to be true for $k\leq 7$:

> Let $V$ be the set of $k$ distinct positive integers with $v_1<v_2<...<v_k$ Then $$\exists
> t\in [0,1]\quad \forall v_i\in V\quad \|tv_i\|\geq \frac{1}{k+1}$$

where $||x||$ denotes the distance from $x$ to the nearest integer.

It is known that for $k+1$ runners, one can assume the following WLOG:

- $\gcd(v_1,...,v_k)=1$
- $(k+1)|v_1$
- $V$ is neither the set of arithmetic/geometric progression nor prime numbers.

Although it wasn't stated in any paper, it is trivially verifiable that one can also assume the following WLOG:

- $\forall r\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $2\leq r\leq k+1$, $\exists v_i\in V$ s.t. $r|v_i$.
- $\forall r\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $k+2\leq r\leq 2k+1$ and $2|r$, $\exists v_i\in V$ s.t. $r|v_i$.

What can I further assume about $V$?

The first three assumptions were stated in [View-obstruction: a shorter proof for 6 lonely runners](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.96.8882&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Jérôme Renault, which is also a nice introduction to LRC along with the corresponding Wikipedia page ([Lonely runner conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonely_runner_conjecture)). [The lonely runner with seven runners](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/download/v15i1r48/pdf) by Barajas is also a relevant reference.

Comment: You may wish to add a link to some background on the LRC, for readers not familiar with it

Comment: It might be worth including in your list that we can assume the speeds are integers, which at least is not obvious to me. It is proved in Section 4 here: http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v8i2r3

Comment: In response to @YemonChoi, this previous MO question has some references: [*Not-lonely runners*](http://mathoverflow.net/q/176822/6094). [Will Sawin's answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/176881/6094) establishes only "logarithmic distance between upper and lower bounds."

Comment: You are probably interested in this recent blog post of Terry Tao as well: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/05/13/a-remark-on-the-lonely-runner-conjecture/

Comment: @Math.StackExchange I see that $k+1$ divides (w.l.o.g.) one the $v_i$'s, but why should it divide the smallest member $v_1$?