# Has the following problem, resembling the lonely runner conjecture, been studied?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics

Given $n$, what is the smallest value $\delta_n$ satisfying the following:

> For any group of $n$ runners with constant but distinct speeds,
> starting from the same point and running clockwise along the unit
> circle,  there exists a moment, at which the length of each of $n$
> empty circle segments between two consecutive runners does not exceed
> $\delta_n$.

More formally, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $M=\{m_1,\dots,m_n\} \subset \mathbb{N}$, and $t \in [0,1]$, we sort the fractional parts of the values $tm_i$ in ascending order: $0 \le \{tm_{i_1}\} \le\dots\le \{tm_{i_n}\} \le 1$. Then we consider the longest empty segment between two consecutive 'runners':
$$ \text{LongestArc}(M,t) := \max\Big\{ \{tm_{i_2}\}-\{tm_{i_1}\}, \dots, \{tm_{i_n}\}-\{tm_{i_{n-1}}\}, 1+\{tm_{i_1}\}-\{tm_{i_n}\} \Big\}.$$
Finally, we put
$$ \delta_n := \mathop{\smash{\mathrm{sup}}}_{|M|=n} \inf_{t \in [0,1]} \text{LongestArc}(M,t).$$

Has the problem of finding these values (or, perhaps, an equivalent one) been studied earlier? I have looked through some papers related to the [Lonely Runner Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonely_runner_conjecture) (including [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.07289)) but found nothing.

It is clear that $\delta_2=\frac12$. With a little more effort goes $\delta_3=\frac25$, one of the 'extremal' sets here is $M=\{0,1,3\}$. One may check that $\delta_4 \ge \frac13$ by taking $M=\{0,1,2,4\}$. I suspect this bound to be tight. Maybe someone sees a counterexample or a short argument, why is that so?

For large $n$, I believe I can show that $\delta_n \ge \frac{\log n -O(\log \log n)}{n}$. However, I don't have any (decent) upper bound on $\delta_n$ apart from the fact that $\delta_n=o(1)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Finally, I found that the 'dual' problem concerning the values
$$ \epsilon_n := \inf_{|M|=n} \mathop{\smash{\mathrm{sup}}}_{t \in [0,1]} \text{LongestArc}(M,t)$$
has earlier been [considered](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176822/not-lonely-runners) on MathOverflow (not in the literature, though). One may also state two more 'dual' extremal problems related to the shortest arc (instead of the longest one), but I haven't found anything published about them as well.

I would appreciate any related reference!

Comment: In case anyone wonders how to get the lower bound $\delta_n \ge \frac{\log n-O(\log \log n)}{n}$. Long story sort, one may take a 'random' $n$-element subset of $[n\log n]$ to do so.

Comment: As for the upper bound $\delta_n=o(1)$, there must be a trivial explanation for this, but I have only a rather technical one. Note that if the fractional parts $\{tm_{i}\}$ are 'almost independently' distributed on the circle, then a 'random' $t$ provides a good upper bound for these runners. Finally, observe that you can always pick such a group of 'independent' runners from a 'sufficiently large' set $M$

Comment: You seem to assume that their velocities are rational, is it clear that it is sufficient to consider this case?

Comment: The trivial upper bound is $\delta_n=O(n^{-1/2})$ but it is so far from your $\frac{\log n}{n}$ that I'd rather wait for somebody with more knowledge in these matters to comment...

Comment: @FedorPetrov I think the same argument that for the usual lonely runners conjecture implies integral speeds are sufficient does the trick ( Consider the closure of the runner's orbits in $(S^1)^n$, note that this is a subtorus defined by integral equations, and conclude that it contains a circle of integral slope.)

Comment: @fedja I think it's worth posting! I tried to prove a bound and didn't even get that far...

Comment: @WillSawin OK, enjoy! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer to the question as posed is "yes", see Konyagin-Ruzsa-Schlag (2011)

[https://gauss.math.yale.edu/~ws442/papers/DILATES.pdf](https://gauss.math.yale.edu/%7Ews442/papers/DILATES.pdf)

It looks like nothing beyond the bounds discovered in the comments and Fedja's answer above is known.

Answer (score 13):

OK, since Will thinks it is worth posting, here it goes. This is not an answer, just setting up the triviality level. As usual, the circle will be identified with $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$.

Let $\psi$ be the piecewise linear $1$ periodic function that is $0$ at $0$, raises to $1$ at $\delta/2$, drops down to $0$ at $\delta$ and then stays $0$ throughout the rest of the period (the well-known "triangle hump", just shifted forward from its usual center). We have the Fourier expansion
$$
\psi(x)=\frac{\delta}2+\sum_{k\ne 0}c_ke^{2\pi ikx}
$$
with $\sum_{k\ne 0}|c_k|=1-\frac\delta 2<1$.

We want to find $t$ such that for every runner moving at the speed $v_0\in V$ ($V$ is the set of all speeds), we have
$$
\Psi_{v_0}(t)=\sum_{v\in V} \psi(vt-v_0t)\ne 0\,.
$$
This will mean that there is at least one runner in the interval of length $\delta$ ahead of every runner, so the maximal gap is at most $\delta$.

However
$$
\Psi_{v_0}(t)=\frac{\delta n}2+\sum_{k\ne 0}c_ke^{-2\pi i kv_0t}F(kt)
\\
\ge 
\frac{\delta n}2-\sum_{k\ne 0}|c_k||F(kt)|\ge
\frac{\delta n}2-\sqrt{\sum_{k\ne 0}|c_k||F(kt)|^2}
$$
where $F(t)=\sum_{v\in V}e^{2\pi i vt}$.

Note now that for each $k\ne 0$, the mean value of $|F(kt)|^2$ (in the sense of almost-periodic functions, i.e., $\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_{-T}^T\dots\,dt$) is $n$, so the mean value of the sum under the square root is $<n$. Thus, we are fine if $\frac{\delta n}2-\sqrt n\ge 0$, i.e., if $\delta\ge \frac 2{\sqrt n}$.

*Edit:* I guess that in the view of mathworker21's comments, I should emphasize a bit where exactly the real difficulty is. To this end I'll recast the proof into another language avoiding the Fourier transform altogether though it is actually the same proof.

Let $\delta>0$. Consider the functions $\varphi_v(x,t)$ that are 1-periodic in $x$ and given by $\chi_{[0,\delta]}(vt-x)-\delta$ on the period and $\Phi(x,t)=\sum_v\varphi_v(x,t)$. If for some $t$ we have a $2\delta$-gap, then $$
\int_0^1 |\Phi(x,t)|^2\,dx\ge \delta(-n\delta)^2=n^2\delta^3\,.
$$
Thus, if we have that gap for all $t$, we must have
$$
\operatorname{Mean}_t\int_0^1 |\Phi(x,t)|^2\,dx\ge n^2\delta^3
$$
but we have the joint in $x,t$ ortogonality of $\varphi_v$, so the left hand side is just $n\delta(1-\delta)$.

The issue is that when $\delta<n^{-1/2}$, the $n\delta$ bump doesn't rise in the $L^2$ integral sense above standard "pure noise level" $\sqrt{n\delta}$ on $[0,1]\ni x$. Trying to use higher $L^p$ norms is problematic for two reasons. First, the integrals of long products now depend on linear dependences between $v$'s with integer coefficients and second, if all speeds are, say, integers from $1$ to $n$, the initial overcrowding interval of length $\frac \delta n$ will already contributes $n^{p-1}\delta$ to that norm, which is way too much. We really need to get rid of (or, at least, suppress) the positive part of $\Phi$ before averaging and that is not easy with polynomial functions, so one needs some new trick or even some new idea to get something non-trivial (which is more or less the *definition* of "non-trivial").

Comment: Nice! I was trying to choose $t$ such that $\sum_{v_1, v_2\in V}  f( v_1 t -v_2 t)$ is at least its mean value for a suitable test function $f$, and then optimize that sum subject to the $v_i t$ leaving a gap of size $\delta$. The trick where you fix one of the two variables and control the sum by Cauchy-Schwarz is what I was missing. Though perhaps there is a way to translate this idea back into the language I was using, since the sum at the end $\sum_{k\neq 0} |c_k| |F(kt)|^2$ is of the form I was thinking.

Comment: @WillSawin Yeah, but unfortunately this is way too rough and I see no way to upgrade the argument so that it would yield something closer to the expected $1/n$ (times some logarithmic factor). It is interesting that one *can* maintain one fixed interval of length $1/\sqrt n$ free of runners for the $1/\sqrt n$ portion of the time, so if you follow that route, the trivial union bound won't work. Well, I would be as interested as you to see some nontrivial upper estimates now :-)

Comment: @WillSawin Sorry, but I'm confused what you guys are talking about. Fedja's solution never used that $v_0 \in V$. Indeed, his solution shows the desired result directly: there's some $t$ so that for all $x \in \mathbb{T}$, there's some $vt \in (x,x+\delta)$. Also, Fedja, at the end you can just integrate $t$ from $0$ to $1$, right?

Comment: @mathworker21 You're right that the assumption $v_0 \in V$ is not necessary, but I don't think that makes what we said strictly wrong. There doesn't seem to be any advantage to taking $v_0 \notin V$.  One can of course integrate from $0$ to $1$ if the speeds are all integers, but it's cleaner to avoid the reduction to that case if you can.

Comment: @mathworker21 I edited to explain better "what we are talking about" :-). Feel free to ask questions if something is unclear and thanks for thinking of this problem: it looks rather fascinating.

Comment: @WillSawin Ok, thanks. The problem stated $V \subset \mathbb{N}$, but you're right the problem makes sense in more generality. Fedja, thanks for the edit. I'll let you know if I have any ideas, and hopefully vice-versa!